# How would i make the mongoose Schema dynamically according to the other fields value in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to define the schema dynamically according to the condition using mongoose

### Schema

```
new mongoose.Schema({

type: String, //BASIC OR ADVANCE

// only for type = BASIC
name: String,
age: Number


/* 
want these fields too but only if type = ADVANCE
email: String,
password: Number
PhoneNumber: String
*/

});
```

how would i achieve this kind of schema using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what your approach to your database is. you can simply create two types with identifiers as Advance and Basic and use middleware to maintain the flow. Now to answer your question:
something like:

```
new mongoose.Schema({

type: String, //BASIC OR ADVANCE

// only for type = BASIC
name: String,
age: Number,

advance: []
```

And now you can check if advance is empty or not. Seriously it all depends on your approach, how you deal with the problem. Once a Schema is declared you can without the advance field, you can still save data like:

```
const MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));
const doc = new MyModel();
doc.advance = {
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: 1234,
   PhoneNumber: 1234
}
doc.save();
```

But with this structure if you want to know the Schema, you'll think that in your file it is only `name` and `age` and later when you start exploring, you'll find out that you are doing something like this and using a proper structure.
Think of moongoose documents as JavaScript Objects, there is a reason it is known as non-Structured data. Hope this explanation helps.